# Unable to execute script before reboot or shutdown

Tags: scripts, shutdown, 18.04, reboot

I need to execute a script before System shutdown or reboot.

I have created the script called `shutdown-pulse`, which I need to execute and placed in under `/etc/init.d`.

The content of the script is:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "[`date`] Executing" > /var/log/shutdown-pulse.log
# my script to shutdown pulse
echo "[`date`] Done" > /var/log/shutdown-pulse.log
```

The file permission of `shutdown-pulse` is:

```
root@TanLap:/etc/init.d# ls -l shutdown-pulse
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 77 May 26 12:39 shutdown-pulse
```

I have created two symbolic links under `/etc/rc0.d` and `/etc/rc6.d`, respectively with same name `K02shutdown-pulse`:

```
root@TanLap:/etc/rc0.d# ls -l K02shutdown-pulse 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 May 26 12:45 K02shutdown-pulse -> ../init.d/shutdown-pulse
```

And

```
root@TanLap:/etc/rc6.d# ls -l K02shutdown-pulse 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 May 26 12:45 K02shutdown-pulse -> ../init.d/shutdown-pulse
```

I was expecting to see the `shutdown-pulse.log` file created under `/var/log` having some contents after I did the restart. But:

```
root@TanLap:/var/log# ls -l shutdown-pulse.log
ls: cannot access 'shutdown-pulse.log': No such file or directory
```

Any pointer would very helpful to figure out the problem.

Note: **pulse** is the Pulse Secure VPN Client

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are on a newer ubuntu version (ubuntu 16.04 or newer) you should use `systemd` instead of `sysvinit`.

An example could look like this (place it in `/etc/systemd/system/pulse-vpn.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Pulse VPN Client

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStop=/path/to/your/script

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To enable this, run

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl enable pulse-vpn.service
```